# How to send textfield with jquery.post, php+mysql without form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to send textfield with `jquery.post` (ajax) from php without form?
I need send text field using `jquery.post` . I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="form1" class="enviar"> <p>
URL:
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
  <p> JSON:
    <textarea name="json" id="json" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
  </p>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
$("#send") .submit(function(){
var json  = $("#json") .val();
var url = $("#url") .val();
var s = {
"json":json
}
var u = {
    "url":url
    }

$.ajax({
url:u,
type:'post',
data:s,
beforeSend: function (){
        $(".status") .html(" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
        },
success:function(data){
$(".status").html(data);
}
});

});
})
```

PHP:

```
include ('conection.php');
$arr = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
if ($_POST['json']>NULL){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO liciteiro.clientes(client_id,client_descricao,client_razaosocial,client_endereco,client_cidade,client_estado,client_telefone) VALUES ('".$arr[0]['client_id']."','".$arr[0]['client_descricao']."','".$arr[0]['client_razaosocial']."','".$arr[0]['client_endereco']."','".$arr[0]['client_cidade']."','".$arr[0]['client_estado']."','".$arr[0]['client_telefone']."')")or die(mysql_error());
}
else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

But this code doesn't send anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will send data after click on send button
Html

```
<div id="form1" class="enviar"> 
<p>URL:<input type="text" name="url" id="url" /></p>
<p> JSON:<textarea name="json" id="json" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="send" value="send" id="send" /></p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#send").click(function(){
        var json  = $("#json") .val();
        var url = $("#url") .val();
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'post',
            data:{json: json},
            beforeSend: function (){
                $(".status") .html(" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
            },
            success:function(data){
                $(".status").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Working Very Well!!!, Hey one more, how i do send to server and return data posted in my mysql return to other textarea? how i put in ajax?

Comment: I have another text area this text field I want to return the values ​​that were entered in the database with this code you helped me.

follows the code of my other text area you would like to receive the data entered in the database.

  <textarea name="status" id="status" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>

Comment: So u want whatever data of textarea(id is `json`), u entered in database that will go in second textarea which id is `status` right. for that you have to put this line in success msg of ajax `$(".status").html(json);` or `$(".status").val(json);`. both will work

Comment: For example i send to server select * from .... and the textarea return datas if have, else text field is blank, do you have example for me ? please

Answer (score 0):

You could add id to you button and use

```
$("#my-button-id").click
```

Or you can try this

```
$(function(){
    $('#form1 input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var json  = $("#json") .val();
        var url = $("#url") .val();
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'post',
            data:{json: json},
            beforeSend: function (){
                $(".status") .html(" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
            },
            success:function(data){
                $(".status").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But you must notice that you can't make ajax queries to other domains, without allow-origin headers.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('#mybutton').on("click",function(){
   var url = $('#url').val()
   $.post(url,
   {text:$('#json').val(), url:url },
   function(data){
         alert("it works");
   })
})
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="json" id="json" cols="45" rows="5"> </textarea>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" />
```

Comment: i put url textfield for send 'textfield text.php', but don't work this code too :(. Please Help :(

Comment: is your javascript code inside $(document).ready(function() {}) ?